# Performance problem with Oracle BULK FETCH and FORALL insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, query-optimization, bulkinsert

I am trying to copied records from one table to another as fast as possible.

Currently I have a simple cursor loop similiar to this:

```
FOR rec IN source_cursor LOOP
   INSERT INTO destination (a, b) VALUES (rec.a, rec.b)
END LOOP;
```

I want to speed it up to be super fast so am trying some BULK operations (a BULK FETCH, then a FORALL insert):

Here is what I have for the bulk select / forall insert.

```
DECLARE 
  TYPE t__event_rows IS TABLE OF _event%ROWTYPE;
  v__event_rows t__event_rows;

  CURSOR c__events IS
    SELECT * FROM _EVENT ORDER BY MESSAGE_ID;
BEGIN
  OPEN c__events;
  LOOP
    FETCH c__events BULK COLLECT INTO v__event_rows LIMIT 10000;  -- limit to 10k to avoid out of memory

    EXIT WHEN c__events%NOTFOUND;

    FORALL i IN 1..v__event_rows.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      INSERT INTO destinatoin
        ( col1, col2, a_sequence) 
        VALUES 
        (  v__event_rows(i).col1,  v__event_rows(i).col2, SOMESEQEUENCE.NEXTVAL );


  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c__events;


END;
```

My problem is that I'm not seeing any big gains in performance so far.  From what I read it should be 10x-100x faster.

Am I missing a bottleneck here somewhere?

Comment: for 100,000 rows, it takes approximately 300 (!) seconds even with the bulk insert

Comment: Is there a reason that you have an ORDER BY in your SELECT?  It could be rather expensive to sort 100,000 rows and that doesn't seem to be necessary.  Also your %NOTFOUND check needs to happen after your FORALL-- otherwise, if you fetch less than 10,000 rows in the last iteration, you won't insert those rows.

Comment: thanks!  i will removing the order by, but i dont think its going to get me quite to the speed im looking for... i will try to get a tkprof analysis and update this later.  good catch with the %NOTFOUND

Comment: Do you have a trigger in your destination table?  Also, if you're just copying data from one table to another, can you use a SQL statement instead of PL/SQL?

Comment: On a related note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987013/bulk-insert-into-oracle-database-which-is-better-for-cursor-loop-or-a-simple-se

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only benefit your code has over a simple `INSERT`+`SELECT` is that you save exceptions, plus (as Justin points out) you have a pointless `ORDER BY` which is making it do a whole lot of meaningless work. You then don't have any code to do anything with the exceptions that were saved, anyway.

I'd just implement it as a `INSERT`+`SELECT`.

Comment: And you can use a LOG ERRORS clause on the INSERT to save exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You donot have to use loops unnecessarily until it is required in the coding itself.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: yeah but the code requires some tips for better performance issues.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it should be a comment :)