# Best way to bulk insert data into Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am going to create a lot of data scripts such as INSERT INTO and UPDATE

There will be 100,000 plus records if not 1,000,000

What is the best way to get this data into Oracle quickly?  I have already found that SQL Loader is not good for this as it does not update individual rows.

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I will be writing an application to do this in C#

Comment: search for "Oracle bulk insert"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load the records in a stage table via [SQL*Loader](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL003). Then use bulk operations:

- INSERT INTO SELECT (for example ["Bulk Insert into Oracle database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987013/bulk-insert-into-oracle-database-which-is-better-for-cursor-loop-or-a-simple-se))
- mass UPDATE (["Oracle - Update statement with inner join"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join))
- or a single [MERGE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm#i2081218) statement

Comment: If I wanted to do an update of one row could I do an inner join on the same table or would that not work

Comment: The typical scenario is that you have many rows to load. Each row will be either inserted if new, or updated into the target table. This is the standard case for a MERGE statement. It's not clear if it's applicable in your case.

Comment: Is there a way to use SQL*Loader when the records are in-memory and not in a file? Say, for example, in a spark data frame.

Answer (score 6):

To keep It as fast as possible I would keep it all in the database.
Use [external tables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) (to allow Oracle to read the file contents),
and create a stored procedure to do the processing.

The update could be slow, If possible, It may be a good idea to consider creating a new table based on all the records in the old (with updates) then switch the new & old tables around.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a spreadsheet program like MS Excel or LibreOffice Calc? This is how I perform bulk inserts.

1. Prepare your data in a tabular format.
2. Let's say you have three columns, A (text), B (number) & C (date). In the D column, enter the following formula. Adjust accordingly.

`="INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (COL_A, COL_B, COL_C) VALUES ('"&A1&"', "&B1&", to_date ('"&C1&"', 'mm/dd/yy'));"`