# JDBC Commit is not reflecting in Oracle DB

Tags: multithreading, oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jdbc

My requirement is I have to commit 4Million records to Oracle DB.

For that, I have developed a Java program which starts 10 threads.  It's a producer and consumer design. Producer pushes data(Range. Ex. 1-1000) for every consumer (Java Thread). Consumers​ consumes the data  and commits that range from one table to another table from Different DBs.

In consumer whenever thread commits data to DB I am logging the range and total no of records committed.

Everything is running smoothly, but after few minutes on console, it's logged that committed records as 90,000 but when I check in DB count is just 40,000.

Even Java program committed data but in Oracle DB why count is less?

After that I came to know multiple commits slow down the process. I am using proper connection pooling and batch processing.

I cannot create DB Link, or can't use another approach for this task. I have to use any Java technology. Normal JDBC , Hibernate or any other technology.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Your time will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You have to add the piece of java code that deals with your transaction. No one can guess that what is wrong with it without seeing it.

Comment: Instead of writing your own code, have you read about Oracle's bulk insert options?  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987013/bulk-insert-into-oracle-database-which-is-better-for-cursor-loop-or-a-simple-s

Comment: Please note that I copying data from AS400 to Oracle DB. I have to read data from AS400 data using Java program and then commit to Oracle DB.

Comment: @Rohit -- Give me some time, I will add the code. I am using. I think then one of you will be able to help.